# React class prop onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, listitem

This is my scenario

```
<List>
    {mainTags.map((mainTagItem) => {
    return (
        <ListItem onClick={() => { setMainTag(mainTagItem.tag.tagId) }} button className={classes.mainTagItem}>
        <div className={classes.mainTagCircle}></div>
        <ListItemText
            primary={mainTagItem.tag.name}
        />
        </ListItem>
    )
    })}
</List>
```

when i click on my `ListItem` ( that becomes selected ) i want the element `<div className={classes.mainTagCircle}>` has an active class

For Example:

```
<div classes={{ root: !!listItemSelected ? classes.mainTagCircleActive : classes.mainTagCircle, }}></div>
```

I have already a method `onClick` in my `ListItem`, how can i apply this logic?

Comment: given that it seems there is only one active, `mainTag === mainTagItem.tag.tagId` logic wouldn't work?

Comment: Can you please provide the answer with code example, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given that you have a `mainTag` state you could compare with your element `tagId` to define which class to select. If it's the same as your state then `active` class wil be returned:

```
<div className={
  mainTag === mainTagItem.tag.tagId 
    ? classes.mainTagCircleActive
    : classes.mainTagCircle}>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution with a library

You could try with this library [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx). Then do something like this:

```
function Component() {
  const [mainTag, setMainTag] = useState(null);

  return (
   <List>
    {mainTags.map((mainTagItem) => {
      return (  
       <ListItem onClick={() => { setMainTag(mainTagItem.tag.tagId) }} className= 
         {clsx([classes.mainTagItem, mainTag === mainTagItem.tag.tagId ? : 
         'activeClass': 'defaultClass' ])}>
        <div className={classes.mainTagCircle}></div>
        <ListItemText
            primary={mainTagItem.tag.name}
        />
        </ListItem>
       )
    })}
   </List>
  )
}
```

### Solution without libraries

```
function Component() {
  const [mainTag, setMainTag] = useState(null);

  return (
   <List>
    {mainTags.map((mainTagItem) => {
      return (  
       <ListItem onClick={() => { setMainTag(mainTagItem.tag.tagId) }} className={
         mainTag === mainTagItem.tag.tagId 
         ? classes.mainTagCircleActive
         : classes.mainTagCircle}
        />
        </ListItem>
       )
    })}
   </List>
  )
}
```